# How to set Oracle time zone region in tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, timezone

I have a tomcat5 server which connects to an Oracle DB and I like to specify the Oracle session time zone.

I managed to define it by adding `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=Europe/Zurich"` to config file `tomcat5.conf`. Problem is when I query in Oracle `SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM dual;` I get `+02:00`

Currently this is OK, however it will become wrong in winter season when daylight-saving-time is off - unless I restart the tomcat server.

How can I set time zone to region name (e.g. `Europe/Zurich`) instead of UTC offset (like `+02:00`)? I would like to avoid running explicit `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = ...;` in my Oracle.

Comment: Is it possible you have a database logon trigger that is setting the session time zone explicitly to +02:00? Or - perhaps more likely - something else in the config is losing or replacing that setting? What session time zone do you see if you connect to the same DB and account via SQL\*Plus?

Comment: The same as defined by environment variable (or Registry settings) `ORA_SDTZ` - as expected.

Comment: Logon trigger would be one solution, however in this case I would stay on `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = ...;` inside my PL/SQL code. Apart from than I don't have permissions to create database triggers on this database.

Comment: I was asking whether you already had one, rather than recommending you add one *8-) But it seems not anyway if SQL\*Plus is OK. The `-D` flag you're using does what you expect, so for some reason it doesn't seem to be reaching the JVM. I'd check that there isn't a later setting of `JAVA_OPTS` that's trashing this one, and that the final JVM call actually uses that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, Tomcat5? Tomcat 5.5 has been [decommissioned](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-55-eol.html) in 2012. Well, apart from that: I'd recommend to fix this in a different way: Storing Timezone-infested data in the backend is a huge mess, always. Thus, you should always purely store UTC and not worry about any daylight-saving, user's geolocation or current timezone, unless you're presenting the data to the user. Only then (and on input) can you relate it to the current timezone for the current user and transform to/from UTC accordingly.

Thus, the question that you ask *might* seem logical, but will lead to *a lot* of pain later. Save yourself the pain and go UTC on the backend.

You already know how to set Tomcat's default timezone, you might want to be able to handle user-specific timezones in addition, but that's a completely different beast.

Comment: Yes, I know it is old. It's a 3rd party application which is not maintained anymore, so upgrade would be a bigger project. Anyway, it is working as you proposed but how to present correct values if time zone is not properly set for current user (i.e the tomcat user), that's what I try to achieve.

Comment: If the user didn't configure their time zone, show them the default, including an indicator for the time zone. I could also ask back: how do you decide currently which time zone to choose?

Comment: The time zone I have to choose is "Europe/Zurich". The problem is, I am not able to tell this the application, resp. the database. Somewhere it automatically changes it to "+02:00" which is not the same! Well, as of today it does not matter, but end of October it will do.

Comment: I'm not able to tell this the application" - well, that's basic use of the time-related datatypes. Again: There's no need to configure this on the database: Assume everything the database saves and reveals is UTC. The datatypes in a table typically are unaware of timezones. If you can hardcode Europe/Zürich - that will make your application simpler (until, one day, you'll need to implement a user's different timezone). Saving timezone infested data to the database is just plain wrong.

Comment: I don't need to configure it on the database, I have to define it for Oracle user session in order to return date values in required format (defined by 3rd party application - yes, it must be a string! The tomcat provides a SOAP response which is XML which is text by definition) The topic is not how to store date/time values in database, I am pretty much aware about this.